# using += and ternary operator in java clarification

Tags: java, operators, ternary

### I was running through some practice questions for an upcoming exam and came across a question that me nor my class mates can seem to understand. It is as follows:

where all variables are int or int array.

### score += (rounds[i]) ? i + START : 0

How does the ternary operator work in java with += ?
This is my understanding:

so it is score += round[i] == i+start or == 0.

Is this a correct understanding?

Kind regards,
James

Comment: won't compile if `rounds` is an int array.

Comment: thanks, even if it wont compile could you explain how the ternary operator would work with += ?

Comment: If `rounds` is an `int[]`, this is a Java compile time error. If you're studying for the OCA or OCP Java exam, the correct answer will be "compile time error". You can consider it *like* `if ((rounds[i])) { score += i + START; } else { score += 0; }` hope that helps. Your example has redundant `()`.

Comment: I once actually ran across a real-world Pascal program in my work.  It was quite the novelty.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've run across a real-world [product](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52590_01/doc.440/910-6241-001_rev_b.pdf) with a Pascal OS. That was a ***shock***. But knowing Pascal didn't directly help me there.

Comment: In 1997, I was employed to teach C++.  I inherited lecture notes from my predecessor, who had been a C programmer, and had simply added `//` comments, `cout <<` and `cin >>` to an earlier C course.  These lecture notes completely missed the point of C++, so I threw them away and started over.  I fear that a C programmer teaching Java may go down the same route as my predecessor.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I inherited a set of early C++ documentation covering SABRE and cfront; that seriously set me back in learning C++. I feel your (and you predecessor)'s pain.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Since covid and online classes the quality has gone down alot in all schools. I honestly think w3 schools is better than most Post Secondary schools unless you are studying something very specialized. I have a decent amount of java experience compared to classmates and am the person people in the class come to for questions so this one really through me off.

Comment: @OleV.V. From the question: *where all variables are int or int array.* It's the first sentence of the question proper.

Comment: @Ole V.V.  No context given to me unfortunately other than the line of code I wrote here. I think it was from an online quiz where we have random questions and a fellow student passed it along to me to see if I could understand it. Not entirely sure though as I am waiting on a response for that.

Answer (score 3):

As with any combination of operators, it's a question of operator precedence and (where the operators have the same precedence) associativity.  In Java, the simple assignment and all the operator/assignment operators share the lowest precedence tier.  The ternary operator is the sole occupant of the next higher precedence tier.  Therefore, your expression is equivalent to

```
score += ((rounds[i]) ? (i + START) : 0)
```

That is, the ternary expression is evaluiated, and its result is the right-hand operand of the `+=`.

As others have observed, that's not valid in Java if the type of `rounds[i]` is `int`, though that would be ok in C.  But the expression could be sensible in Java if `rounds[i]` were an array of `boolean`, or it could be rewritten like this ...

```
score += ((rounds[i] != 0) ? (i + START) : 0)
```

... on the assumption that a C-style boolean interpretation of integer `rounds[i]` is what is wanted.

Comment: Because this is for pedagogical purposes, and because I did recently pass the OCP Java 8 exam, I can say all of the parens here are correct **but** they are also completely unnecessary `score += rounds[i] != 0 ? i + START : 0;` would also be correct (and if studying for those exams, you need to know exactly what is legal and what is not legal).

Comment: Of course the parentheses are unnecessary, @ElliottFrisch. Otherwise, adding them would not produce an equivalent expression.  But I suppose it does not hurt to re-emphasize that.  Congratulations on passing the exam.

Comment: No worries. And thanks. But I was really also contrasting with the prof's original form: `score += (rounds[i]) ? i + START : 0` where the parens are (IMO) vestigial.

Answer (score 1):

```
score += (some condition which is true or false) ? value to add if true : value to add if false;
```

Comment: @OleV.V. Again, wasn't me. But this has clear prose to me. It gets an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

We can try it.

```
    int START = 3;

    int score = 0;
    boolean[] rounds = { true, false };
    for (int i = 0; i < rounds.length; i++) {
        score += (rounds[i]) ? i + START : 0;
        System.out.format("i is %d, score is %d%n", i, score);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> i is 0, score is 3
> i is 1, score is 3
> ```

So the first time through the loop `i` is 0 and `rounds[i]` is `true`. In this case Java adds `i` and `START` to get 3 and adds this to `score`. Second time `i` is `1` and `rounds[i]` is `false`, so instead just 0 is added.

The statement you ask about adds a value to `score`. The value added is `i + START` if `rounds[i]` can be evaluated to true and 0 if it’s `false`. If `i` and `START` are both numeric, a number will be added. If `score` is numeric, adding 0 usually makes no difference, so you may think of the statement as adding a value only if `rounds[i]` is true.

> so it is score += round[i] == i+start or == 0.

No, there is no implicit `==` comparison in the statement (as others have said, it requires that `rounds[i]` is a Boolean value, true or false).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It goes fully in depth on what I was asking for clarification on!

Comment: If you like this answer and it meets your requirement you should consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator `?:` is used as follows:

- a = bolean_expression ? this if true : else this if false.

```
        int start = 5;

        // In this case, start was added to itself to obtain 10.                
        start += true ? start  : 0;
        System.out.println(start); // prints 10

        // with out the compound assignment operator (+=) the
        // expression should be enclosed in () 
        start = start + (true ? start : 0);
        System.out.println(start); // prints 20
```

In the above cases, if the boolean was false, the `start` always have the value `5` since `0` would be added each time.

Comment: Thanks man, that is much more clear. Teacher just made a mistake. no wonder why I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: @OleV.V. Not a down voter, but I would like some prose with the answer. Also, you might add an example with `false`.

Comment: Technically, it's the JLS 15.25. [Conditional Operator `? :`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) and described in the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) under "The Conditional Operators".

Comment: Ok, if you really want to get technical, I copied this from the JLS.  *The ternary conditional operator ? : (§15.25)*  So I just use ternary for short.

Comment: @WJS I included a link to that section. It does not include the word ternary. I know it is a ternary. So you're not wrong. But Java doesn't call it that. Don't ask me why. Wait, it includes the language at [15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for some reason. What a pain.